# Ребята-взяли рыбу на 3 кг

Tags: пунктуация

Ребята-взяли рыбу на 3 кг.

Скажите, как правильно? Здесь человек обращается к друзьям и констатирует факт покупки рыбы.

Comment: Без опечатки было бы правильно. А что смущает-то?

Comment: @shampar где тут опечатка-то? Может, я чего-то недопонимаю, но налице не опечатка, а сознательный о пунктуационный выпендрёж.

Comment: behemothus, не я это первый сказал... Надо записать диагноз: СПВ. (Опечаткой назвал крепко зажатое между словами похожее на тире.)

Comment: Там одна рыбина на 3 кило потянула или человек набрал рыбы на такой вес?

Answer (score 2):

*Ребята, мы взяли 3 килограмма рыбы.*

(Я с кем-то купил 3 кг рыбы и, обращаясь к друзьям, сообщаю об этом.)

1. После обращения ставится запятая.
2. Предлог НА можно использовать в случае, если мы говорим о цене — «Я взял клубники на 200 рублей».

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, как правильно? Здесь человек обращается к друзьям и
> констатирует факт покупки рыбы.

Смысл этого высказывания не очень понятен без контекста. А что, "ребята"  не в курсе, что они взяли рыбу? Да и употребление оборота с "на" не оправдано вне какого-то особого контекста (см. ProgRover).

Но в любом случае, если "обращается к друзьям" (то есть к ребятам) то запятая необходима.

***"Ребята, взяли рыбу..."*** - сообщение друзьям-ребятам, что они эту рыбу взяли.

Иное дело, если есть некие "друзья" (не те, которые "ребята") и вот этим друзьям говорящий сообщает, что некие "ребята" (не те, которые "друзья", но им, этим друзьям, известные) взяли рыбу. Тогда Ребята - подлежащее и никаких знаков после себя не требует.

***"Ребята, взяли рыбу..."*** - сообщение друзьям, что ребята "взяли" рыбу.

Повторюсь, в любом случае, смысл высказывания не очень понятен без контекста, а оборот с "на" вызывает вопросы сам по себе.

Comment: это не фраза , вырванная с контекста, это законченное предложение. Ребята- взяли рыбу на 3 кг.Иными словами  , Ребята- мы только что взяли рыбу на 3 кг. Тире ,как бы, придает действию значимость события.

Comment: Вопрос как раз в этом тире- имеет ли оно место быть ?

Comment: @Оксана У меня нет вопрос к тире. Его там быть не должно. Зато у меня появляется всё больше вопросов к вашему стилю. "Имеет место быть" - выражение неправильное.

Comment: Важно понимать, что по-настоящему грамотный человек не станет исправлять каждого, указывая на правильность иметь место и иметь быть по отдельности, а просто будет знать, как этот «гибрид» возник. Понимание динамики и трансформации языка — это и есть настоящая грамотность.

Comment: @Оксана, ваши послания читают не только "по-настоящему" грамотные. И довольно странно, что вы, придя на ресурс, начинаете диктовать своё понимание хороших манер.

Comment: Впрочем, читайте здесь. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_90